# Variable Indirectly Containing 0 Doesn't Echo 0

Tags: batch-file

Trying things out in my program and I encountered somethings. The 0 won't echo. Do you know the cause and solution?

```
@echo off
cls
SET x=0000
if %x:~-2%==00 ( set x=%x:~-2% )
echo %x%
echo %x:~-1%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a trailing space before the closing bracket.